# Understanding clear and float

Tags: html, css

I am learning `clear` property in CSS.

What my understanding is `clear: both` will move the element such a way that on both sides other float elements are not present. But here B is present next right to C. Isn't this a conflict?

```css
#A {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
#B {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
#C {
  float: right;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>This is a main test statement</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box1" id="A">A</div>
    <div class="box2" id="B">B</div>
    <div class="box3" id="C">C</div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: both Is a keyword indicating that the element is moved down to clear past both left and right floats. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Comment: @j08691: So now I need to use clear property on C to move it away from B?

Comment: Yes, if you want C after (below) B then yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clear` applies to elements appearing earlier in the DOM, so it's doing what it's supposed to do. B is clear of A. Per [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats)  about `clear`

> "This property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may not
>   be adjacent to an earlier floating box. The 'clear' property does not
>   consider floats inside the element itself or in other block formatting
>   contexts."